# How to modify an AngularJs directive template based on the value of attribute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a dropdown directive built on top of Angular Bootstrap typeahead.

I want the consumer of the directive to be able to supply an attribute (limit-to-list) which determines whether or not user input is limited to list members.   In the uib-typeahead directive, this is achieved by setting the typeahead-editable attribute "true" or "false"

Because my directive encapsulates the uib which generates the dropdown, I need to change the template of my directive to change its behavior accordingly, but I can't figure out how that can be done.  I tried to modify the string template in the return clause of my directive, but that does not work, I guess because the value of the template is read before the return function is processed?

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("dropDown",  function () {
  var mt=mydropdowntemplate;

  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var limitToList = attrs["limit-to-list"]=="false"; 
        var editable = !limitToList;
        if (editable) {
            mt=mt.replace("typeahead-editable='false'","typeahead-editiable='true'");
        }
        console.log("template: "  + mt )
        var list = scope[attrs["list"]];
        var length=list.length
        var valueName = attrs["value"];
        var idName = attrs["key"];       
    },
    template: mt  //This has the value of mt prior to the replace function above    
  }
})
```

By looking at the page, I can see that the actual template used was the one before the change applied in the result block.

[Plunker link](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/dc7bxC3rUjijvh90)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `link` function is an inappropriate place to modify the template as it is executed after the template is compiled. Instead use the function form of the template property
to modify the template:

```
angular.module("app").directive("dropDown",  function () {
  var mt=mydropdowntemplate;

  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var list = scope.$eval(attrs.list);
        var length=list.length
        var valueName = attr.value;
        var idName = attrs.key;       
    },
    template: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
         var limitToList = tAttrs.limitToList=="false"; 
         var editable = !limitToList;
         if (editable) {
             mt=mt.replace("typeahead-editable='false'","typeahead-editiable='true'");
         }
        console.log("template: "  + mt )
        return mt;
    } 
  }
})
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-).

Answer (score 2):

Use 'scope' property of the returned object to pass data from through attributes.
Like so, you can use 'bindToController" property, if you use controllerAs syntax.
Well i'm strongly recommend to use component approach in replace to directive.